# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'weight'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two files in one folder, which are
[image]

"converters.py" is a module while "app.py" is a python file which tests it

here are the contents in the "converters.py module":

```
class KgLbs:
def __init__(self, weight):
    self.weight = weight

def lbs_to_kg(self):
    return self.weight * 0.45

def kg_to_lbs(self):
    return self.weight / 0.45
```

and here are the ones in the "app.py" script:

```
from converters import KgLbs as kglbs

weight = int(input("Weight: "))
weight = kglbs.kg_to_lbs(weight)
print(weight)
```

and that's the error it gives me when I input an integer:

```
Weight: 52
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 4, in <module>
    weight = kglbs.kg_to_lbs(weight)
  File "C:\Users\Cyntexia\PycharmProject\Test\converters.py", line 8, in kg_to_lbs
    return self.weight / 0.45
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'weight'
```

all i wanna do is input a simple integer, and then it will be converted to weight i desire altho this error comes in my goddamn way

Comment: You should create an object of class "KgLbs" and call "kg_to_lbs" on this object.

Comment: Should be `kglbs(weight).kg_to_lbs()`

Comment: `weight = int(input("Weight: "))` does not initialize weight of instance variable `weight` of class `KgLbs`; instead it creates a new one

Comment: is the indentation intentional? because, if you want  `lbs_to_kg`, `kg_to_lbs` and `__init__` to be class-methods, they need to be indented.

Comment: your methods ` lbs_to_kg` and `kg_to_lbs` act on the same variable (`self.weight`). but that is bogus, as the `weight` would either be in `kg` **or** in `lbs` and one of the converters should do nothing; unless you really want `@staticmethod`s as suggested in  @MrGeek 's solution (in which case, you don't need any member variables at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way you designed your class, you have to use it in this way:

```
weight = KgLbs(weight).kg_to_lbs()
```

To use your way, you need to define your methods as `@classmethods` and pass the `weight` as an argument to them (no need for `__init__` here):

```
class KgLbs:
  @staticmethod
  def lbs_to_kg(weight):
      return weight * 0.45

  @staticmethod
  def kg_to_lbs(weight):
      return weight / 0.45

weight = int(input("Weight: "))
weight = KgLbs.kg_to_lbs(weight)
print(weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialised the weight for the object. It should've been like

```
from converters import KgLbs as kglbs

weight = int(input("Weight: "))
obj = kglbs(weight)
print(obj.kg_to_lbs())
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is a strongly-typed language, and you are assigning a value of type `int` to the `weight` variable.
Why do you think this `int` value should behave like a  `KgLbs`?

use this instead:

```py
from converters import KgLbs as kglbs

weight = kglbs(int(input("Weight: ")))
weight = weight.kg_to_lbs()
print(weight)
```